# Docker container blocking text/event-stream

Tags: javascript, java, docker, event-stream

I am working with Docker containers and live streaming of `text/event-stream` events. I am using [this example here](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/html5-server-sent-events-java-servlets-example/). When I deploy that example as a Java EE WAR on a TomCat server on my local machine, everything works fine, and I see the Webpage updating live when the server sends random event data.

[image: Event stream example running on TomCat locally]

[image: Server side code for the event streaming]

When I deploy this example inside a Docker container based off a TomCat image though, like so:

`docker run -d --name tomcateventstream -p 8081:8080 -P -v ~/Coding/Java/webapp:/usr/local/tomcat/webapps tomcat`

In this latter case the example doesn't work. The events are apparently canceled, as shown in these pictures below:

[image: Running in a Docker container on the local machine]

[image: Event stream getting canceled]

Any idea why? I've searched quite a lot around this topic, I've even tried publishing all ports on the Docker side of things, but to no avail. I'm sure I'm missing something very small somewhere, something with the default Docker settings. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem in the end?

Comment: @MarcCostello nope; ended up using WebSockets. You'd think `text/event-stream` just isn't supported and isn't too big of a concern?